# "Heard my mom cry/crying", "leave the door lock/locked"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, infinitives, participles

Two simple examples:

> 1. a. I heard my mom cry.
>      b. I heard my mom crying.
> 2. a. Please leave the door lock always.
>      b. Please leave the door locked always.

Which one, *a* or *b*, is right?

Comment: Is it homework?

Comment: No, its the grammar book's example I confused.The book says sense verb should add original type later,but also give example that doesn't, so I confused that. If you think this should add homework tag I can add it on.

Comment: _Leave_ is not a verb of sense; the question is not about a verb of sense, then, but about using _cry_ or _crying_, _lock_ or _locked_. I would edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Related: [“Heard me <infinitive>” vs. “heard me <present participle>”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96742/heard-me-infinitive-vs-heard-me-present-participle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In (1), either is possible in principle, with a slight difference in emphasis. If you use the "-ing" form, you're focussing a bit more on the "mental image" of the action of crying; if you use the infinitive, you're stating it more as a "matter of fact" occurrence.

In (2), the only possibility of the two is "locked". If you use the infinitive with "leave", then you need to insert "to" as well: "I left him to do the washing up". If you use the causative "let" (don't confuse the meanings of these two verbs, which are slightly different), then no "to" is used: "I let him do the washing up".

N.B. In (2), the word order you have wouldn't be so natural, at least in UK English: one would tend to say "Please always leave...".

Comment: But interestingly: “Please leave the door locked at all times”.