# "Heard me [infinitive]" vs. "heard me [present participle]"

Tags: grammaticality, infinitives, present-participles, complements, nonfinite-clause-complementation

"Heard me [infinitive]" vs. "heard me [present participle]"

> - 1. At that time, you wouldn't have heard me **talk** about it.
>   2. At that time, you wouldn't have heard me **talking** about it.
> - 1. At that time, you wouldn't have heard me **condemn** it.
>   2. At that time, you wouldn't have heard me **condemning** it.

Which <strike>one</strike> of the above sentences are incorrect and why?

Comment: With verbs of perception, bot gerund and infinitive can be used. There us very little difference in meaning, if any.

Comment: @Cerberus Thank you. Would you mind telling me the little difference in meaning of the above sentences?

Comment: Please incorporate the title into the question body and restate your question clearly.

Comment: @BrightPolyglot: The difference is too small to analyse, and there may not be any semantic difference at all. If any, it must be pragmatic. See Lawler's answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

None of them are incorrect.

English [sense verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299), unlike most [complement-taking verbs](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complementtypes.pdf),
can take either gerund or infinitive complements.

- *I saw/heard him leave/leaving.*

This is most common with long-distance senses, of course;
-- *She smelled him leaving* is a fairly unlikely (though not ungrammatical) thing to say.

It **may** be (and undoubtedly some people interpret it this way, though others don't)
that

- *I heard him leaving.*

means something like (and may be a variant of)

- *I heard him while he was (in the act of) leaving.*

while

- *I heard him leave.*

means something like

- *I heard the noise produced by his leaving.*

Not a whole lot of difference here, and [for all intensive purposes](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3933) they're synonymous.

Comment: Yeah the difference is almost imperceptible, and I couldn't pinpoint it. The pragmatic difference between *I heard him leave* and *I heard his leaving*, however, is clear.

Comment: Ah, but if we're going to subject this one to [intensive](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/intensive.html) analysis, perhaps we should consider the fact that with some constructions there's still another possibility - *"I heard **his** breathing"*. Which seems perfectly reasonable to me, but unlike the ***him** breathe/breathing* versions, it doesn't work so well with *saw*.

Comment: But that's a noun, not a gerund. _I heard his labored reading of the book_, but not _*I heard his reading the book with difficulty_.

Comment: Given the right context, there is also the difference that the gerund can refer to the subject of the inflected verb, rather than the object: “He was trying to hide in the doorway, but I saw him craning my neck out far as I could”. This is not possible with an infinitive.

Comment: Yes, but in that case _I saw him craning_ is not a constituent; the gerund isn't the complement of _saw_, but rather a final means adverbial clause with deleted _by_, and probly a different intonation. Certainly it works preposed instead of postposed: _He was trying to hide in the doorway, but, craning my neck out as far as I could, I saw him._

Comment: _Great jokes from little ..._

Comment: Here's a good explanation on the difference in meaning http://www.englishgrammar.org/verbs-perception/

Answer (score 0):

I agree that there's not much difference between the two, although the "-ing" form may suggest something that goes on for a while. For example, "I heard him sneeze" suggests that he just sneezes once, whereas "I heard him sneezing" gives more of a sense that the sneezing goes on for a while.

On a separate point, the expression is not "for all intensive purposes" (John Lawler). It's an eggcorn arising from a mishearing of the correct expression, which is "for all intents and purposes".

Comment: [Point 2] If you follow John's link, you will see that he's well aware of this.