# Why do we use the objective case pronoun "me" in "He can watch me clean the car"?

Tags: infinitives, subjects, personal-pronouns, grammatical-case, catenative-verbs

> He can watch **me** clean the car.

In this sentence, the pronoun *me* is used as the object of the verb *watch.* But isn't *me* also acting as the subject of the verb 'clean' and therefore should be *I* instead? Obviously 'he can watch me clean the car' sounds correct but why is it this way?  Is there a rule that governs this?

**Reopen note**

This question has been linked to this question here:

- ["Heard me [infinitive]" vs. "heard me [present participle]"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96742/heard-me-infinitive-vs-heard-me-present-participle)

However, that question is clearly about whether to use an infinitive or a gerund-participle form after the verb *hear*. This question is as described above. It is about the function of the pronoun *me* in sentences like the one described.

Comment: No, *me* is not acting as the subject of the verb *clean*. Very simple test: do you watch him clean the car, or do you watch him cleans it? Did you see us clean the car, or did you see us cleaned it?

Comment: This is a different question, surely? In my opinion, this one is about catenatives and raised objects, not infinitivals vs participials.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Erm, that's a pretty dodgy test. Are you arguing that *she* is not he Subject of the verb *leave* in  *It's essential that she leave immediately* ?

Comment: Not enough room here to post a reply to the OP's question.

Comment: @BillJ It's now open for you to give an answer.

Answer (score 2):

"me clean the car" is an infinitive phrase as the object of the main verb. The subject of infinitives is always in the oblique case.

```
sbj: He
vrb: watched
        obj: me clean the car (infin)
```

Other examples of infinitive phrases as objects:

```
My mother made me take the trash out
She wanted us to come
We asked him to go home
```

Answer (score 0):

In 'he watched me clean the car', 'I cleaned the car' is an event that is the object of the verb 'watched'.  The form is called 'raising to object'.  The sub-subject is in object case and the sub-verb is infinite (tense is implied by the main clause).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @William, the object complement clause *me clean the car* has *me* as a subject.
It also has an infinitive verb phrase without the normal *to* complementizer.
As pointed out by @Ami, this construction is called "raising to object" (or ***[B-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf)***).

B-Raising produces a noun phrase that's in the ideal position for it to function as object of the upstairs clause **and** as subject of the downstairs one as well -- at the end of the first and the beginning of the second.  Since there are two parsings available, both can be used, and often are.

- *[1 He watched [2 **me** 1] clean the car 2]*

B-Raising also produces a construction that's essentially identical to B-Equi, like

- *[1 He told me 1] [2 (for me) to clean the car 2]*

where **me** in fact occurs twice, as the indirect object of *told*, and also as the subject of *clean*.
I.e, it was me he told, **and** it was me cleaning the car; B-Equi is why *me* occurs once instead of twice.

So there are tests for Raising, which are explained in the link above.
And sense verbs like *watch* have special codicils, like omitting the *for-to* infinitive complementizer.