# I thought I heard you call my name

Tags: past-tense

I read several sentences, like these:

1. "I thought I heard you call my name", should this be "I thought I heard you called my name"?
2. "Yesterday I saw a lion kiss a deer", should this be "Yesterday I saw a lion kissed a deer"?

Comment: Related, “Heard me [infinitive]” vs. “heard me [present participle]”(http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96742/heard-me-infinitive-vs-heard-me-present-participle).

Answer (score 1):

No, the originals are correct. If the originals included the word "that" (I saw that a lion kissed a deer) that would also be correct.

Comment: So "I saw that a lion kissed a deer" is correct, but "I saw that a lion kiss a deer" is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, you are right on both points. Note that the versions that include "that" imply indirect knowledge, that you heard or read about the event. The versions without "that" imply that you witnessed the event.

Answer (score 0):

You have run into a construct called the bare infinitive.  As you'll recall the infinitive form of a verb is the word *to* plus the plain form of the verb.  (This is also the form used by the first person present tense.)  Infinitives are nonfinite verbs, (i.e., they don't form the main predicates of senteneces, and they are *not* inflected for tense).  Infinitives instead find places in sentences also occupied by others constructs, often noun phrases.  Let's take an example:

> I wanted **to kiss** my wife.

The infinitive *to kiss* here is the direct object of *wanted*.  Notice that (1) this is the kind of position that might be occupied by a *noun phrase*:

> I wanted *a kiss from my wife*.

and (1) even though the main verb *wanted* is in the past tense, the infinitive doesn't reflect a tense.  There's so such grammatical thing as *to kissed*.  In the present tense, the infinitive won't change:

> I want **to kiss** my wife.

In some cases, it is idiomatic to drop the infinitive's companion *to*, making it a bare infinitive:

> I thought I heard you [to] call my name.

Here the [to] just means that *call* is part of an infinitive. The *to* is unexpressed and it would be ungrammatical to express it.  The opposite is true in other cases.  For instance

> I thought I told you **to call** my name.