# See somebody do/doing something

Tags: perfect-aspect, progressive-aspect, gerund-vs-infinitive, sense-verbs, nonfinite-clause-complementation

Consider these two variations:

1. Every morning, tourists **can see soldiers raise** the national flag in the square.
2. Every morning, tourists **can see soldiers raising** the national flag in the square.

What are the differences?

Which sounds more natural?

Comment: _See_ is a [sense verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/96744/15299), and they have their own special syntax. In particular, _see, hear,_ and _feel_, among others, can take **either** infinitive complements (_I saw him leave_) **or** gerund complements (_I saw him leaving_) grammatically. There's no difference in meaning, and no difference in formality; it's all speakers' choice.

Comment: The difference here has been covered before, so I'll stick to a 'comment'. Sense verbs (see, hear, feel; watch [but not notice, film, observe]) can take either a bare infinitive or a present participle complement. The bare infinitive gives more the sense of a completed action ('I saw him fall'), while the participle complement brings the durative aspect of what is/was being watched etc into focus ('I saw him falling'; 'I love to hear them practising').

Comment: @tchrist (1) Couldn't find them in a swift search. (2) Is it best to amalgamate all these? (3) Have you developed an easily searchable duplicate database?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'd say that the first linked duplicate has an answer worthy of canonicalization for these types of questions, and the second one worthy of beatification. :)

Comment: @tchrist There's already a St John Scholasticus.