# The roulette players silently watched the wheel spin around/round

Tags: tenses

The roulette players silently watched the wheel spin around/round

Which use spin but not span in past tense? Thank you.

Comment: It’s a rather odd image to have a roulette wheel *spanned* around; *span* is a linear concept whereas *spin* is a circular one.

Comment: I think you mean "spun".

Comment: (But the watching was in present tense -- spin.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Heard me \[infinitive\]" vs. "heard me \[present participle\]"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96742/heard-me-infinitive-vs-heard-me-present-participle) '
<< English sense verbs, unlike most complement-taking verbs,
can take either gerund or infinitive complements. 
_I saw/heard him leave/leaving._ ... >> (J Lawler)

Answer (score 1):

Spin is an infinitive. It is part of an adverbial free modifier

The roulette players silently watched the wheel spin around/round ->

The roulette players silently watched the wheel **as it spun around/round**

Comment: So it is like watching the wheel to spin around?

Comment: No, @Fsa. Many verbs of perception (eg _see_, _hear_, _watch_, _feel_) can take an infinitive clause without "to" as an object. They can also take a "that" clause, and an "-ing" clause, but not an infinitive clause with "to". As usual, this is an unpredictable property of the particular verbs. _Expect_ can take an infinitive clause with "to", but not one without "to".