# I didn't see him go there/I didn't see him going there

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, verbs

Does the verb see accept an embedded clause with a bare infinitive verb like help or make(in the active voice)?

Comment: With regard to your title, I would understand the first to mean 'As far as I know, he didn't go there', and the second '[I know he did go, but] I failed to notice it'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Heard me \[infinitive\]" vs. "heard me \[present participle\]"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96742/heard-me-infinitive-vs-heard-me-present-participle) (John Lawler's answer on [sense verb] + [DO] +  [infinitive] or [present participle]). Note that the second sentence is ambiguous; for the shared sense, the continuous variant hints at a more protracted viewing.