# "I hold doors open just to see people do that little run" - do vs doing

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

What would be the correct form and why? Both could be used, but I think the do version is colloquial. I am interested in the reason though

I hold doors open just to see people **do** that little run or I hold doors open just to see people **doing** that little run?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [heard me + infinitive vs heard me present participle?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96742/heard-me-infinitive-vs-heard-me-present-participle/96744#96744) (+ 'saw him leave' v 'saw him leaving') or  [Non-finite clause complementation of complex transitive verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114365/non-finite-clause-complementation-of-complex-transitive-verbs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatical, but have slightly different meanings.

The one you probably want is *do*: there the object is the whole clause *people do that little run*. There's an implied complementiser, such as *that* or *how*.

If you use *doing*, then the object is *people [doing that little run]*, i.e. a noun phrase which contains a participal clause. But the import is that what you are watching is the people, rather than them doing the run. *Doing that little run* modifies (and probably selects) the "people", but the object is still the people.